# looping over array of elements just affects the last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dom

In one of my projects I just discovered, that sometimes iterating over an array of html elements (and change all of them) just affects the last element. When I log the element's attributes I can see that the loop definitily adresses every element but nevertheless visibly just the last element is getting changed.

Can anyone explain me why?

I already figured out, that a solution is to use createElement() and appendChild() instead of insertHTML. I just want to understand why javascript behaves like this.

Here is my example code:

```
/* creating 5 elements and storing them into an array */
var elementArray = [];
for(var n = 0;n<5;n++)
{
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='elmt_"+n+"'>"+n+"</div>\n";
    elementArray[n] = document.getElementById("elmt_"+n);
}

/* loop over these 5 elements */
for(var n = 0;n<5;n++)
{
    console.log(elementArray[n].id); // logs: elmt_0 elmt_1 elmt_2 elmt_3 elmt_4
    elementArray[n].innerHTML = "test"; // changes just the last element (elmt_4) to "test"
}
```

I created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qwe44m1o/1/

Comment: seems like after `document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='elmt_"+n+"'>"+n+"</div>\n";` browser refresh dom and pointer to elements before adding new  not refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1 -* Using `console.log(elementArray[n]);` in your second loop shows that innerHTML in this loop is modifying html inside your array, not in your document. That means that you are storing the **div** element in your array, not **a shortcut** to `document.getElementById("elmt_"+n)`

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fe66m5p/)

---

2 - If you want to store a shortcut in order to target an element by ID, you have to add quotes for `elementArray[n] = "document.getElementById('elmt_"+n+"')";`, and use it with `eval` like this : `eval(elementArray[n]).innerHTML = n+"-test";`

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3ez197o/1/) for this try